# How customize the position of select dropdown

Tags: jquery-select2

In my website, i'm using jquery plugin select2. The plugins works for me but i have got one problem in my webpage. The dropdown element is not positioned correctly

[select dropdown with select2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8uUu.jpg)

Here is my js code

```js
    $('.select-options').select2({
        multiple: true,
        selectOnClose: false,
        closeOnSelect: true
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select-options" name="comp[]" multiple>
  <option  value="1">Comp 1</option>
  <option  value="2">Comp 2</option>
  <option  value="3">Comp 3</option>
  <option  value="4">Comp 4</option>
  <option  value="5">Comp 5</option>
  <option  value="6">Comp 6</option>
  <option  value="7">Comp 7</option>
  <option  value="8">Comp 8</option>
</select>
```

for the positioning of the element, it's an option of select2 (version 4.1.0) or a css rule ? How customize the positionning of element dropdown ?

Thanks so lot

Comment: difficult to answer without your code showing the problem...

Comment: @Frenchy i'm editing my post with my html code. It's better for you ?

Comment: ok so i have saved your code in a snippet and when you execute it no problem, its seems it misses css code. So edit the snippet and add your css code